# Keeping SWT Text box size after setting text

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I use `setText()` on one or both `Text` fields, it resizes the field to the length of the text. How do I prevent that from happening?

```
inner = new Composite(middle, SWT.NONE);
inner.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));

chkbxBtn = new Button(inner, SWT.CHECK);
chkbxBtn.setText("Check box button: ");
chkbxBtn.setSelection(false);

new Label(inner, SWT.NONE).setText("Text field 1: ");
startCol = new Text(inner, SWT.BORDER | SWT.NONE);

new Label(inner, SWT.NONE).setText("Text field 2: ");
endCol = new Text(inner, SWT.BORDER | SWT.NONE);
```

Comment: can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: can you show your full code?

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, SWT does not re-layout after changing the text (or any other property) of a `Text` control (or controls in general). It is your code or a resize event that causes the re-layout.

If you want a control to have a pre-set size, and its parent uses a `GridLayout`, you can set `GridData` with a `widthHint` like this:

```java
GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.widthHint = ...
text.setLayoutData( gridData );
```

However, it is usually a bad idea trying to control the size of widgets. Thus make sure that your layout strategy aligns with best practices of UI design.

Answer (score 2):

There are situations when changes to the text trigger a component re-layout. For example, show an error message as a text validation result (I found it in SWT forms).
Setting the width hint in the GridData for the text component fixes this. Width hint can be set to 0 or the minimum required size.

```
    GridDataFactory.swtDefaults()//
            .grab(true, false)//
            .hint(0, SWT.DEFAULT)// width hint prevents text from expanding to full line
            .align(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER)//
            .applyTo(text);
```